# What is the least obvious Go standard library package you can use to escape a sandbox?

Tags: security, go, sandbox, blacklist

I'm designing a project for a college-level computer security course, and I'm trying to include a vulnerability where code which is "clean" by virtue of a number of risky packages being blacklisted (`unsafe`, `os`, `ioutil`, etc). The question is this: can you think of a way to use other non-obvious Go standard library packages to escape the sandbox? "Escape the sandbox" here means reading/writing files, making network connections, breaking memory safety (which would allow you to do any of the other things), etc.

Things I've tried so far that haven't worked:

- Using the `reflect` package to do unsafe pointer conversions (the `reflect` package seems really safe against this sort of abuse)
- Using the `reflect` package to get access to a reference held by a random stdlib package to some sensitive function like `os.Open` (I haven't found any that actually keep function pointers or anything like that)

Comment: I seriously hope you don't find anything :) You can read about how the Go team sandboxed the playground to see that these guys mean business https://blog.golang.org/playground

Comment: What "sandbox" are you talking about? A bsd jail? linux namespaces? chroot? docker? qemu?

Comment: I'm using the term "sandbox" loosely here - the only sandboxing that's performed is blacklisting certain packages and refusing to compile code that imports packages on this blacklist.

Comment: If you're only blacklisting module name at compile time, it's not really a sandbox then. If I wanted to break out of this, I would drop an assembly thunk into the source to call into whatever runtime function I wanted, or just implement `Syscall`.

Comment: An assembly thunk? You mean like inline assembly? I wasn't aware that was possible in Go.

Comment: There's no inline assembly, it needs to be in its own .s file, but you can do pretty much anything you want in there (though now that I think about it, I'm not sure if you can still JMP or CALL into arbitrary runtime functions).